# Linear Differential System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One of the theorem in "Introduction to ODE by Argawal says,"

If $\Psi(x)$ is a fundamental matrix of the differential system: $$u' = A(x)u \; (*)$$
then for any constant nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix $C$, $\Psi(x)C$ is also a fundamental of $(*)$, and every fundamental matrix of $(*)$ is of the form $\Psi(x)C$ for some constant nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix $C$.

As a consequence of this theorem, we can write $$\Phi(x,x_0) = \Psi(x)\Psi^{-1}(x_0)$$
Where $\Phi(x,x_0)$ is principal fundamental matrix of the system.

So, I am thinking can we also write like this as a consequence of above theorem: 
$$\Phi(x,x_0) = \Phi(x)\Phi^{-1}(x_0)$$
$$\Psi(x,x_0) = \Psi(x)\Psi^{-1}(x_0)$$

Answer (score 0):

$Ψ$ has one argument, $Φ$ has two arguments, where do the versions with the switched argument numbers come from?

$Ψ$ composes any $n$ independent solutions, $Φ(·, x_0)$ solves $Φ'=AΦ$, $Φ(x_0)=I_n$.

But indeed,
$$
Φ(x_2, x_0)=Ψ(x_2)·Ψ^{−1}(x_0)=Ψ(x_2)·Ψ^{−1}(x_1)·Ψ(x_1)·Ψ^{−1}(x_0)\\
=Φ(x_1, x_0)·Φ(x_2, x_1)=Φ(x_1, x_0)·Φ(x_1, x_2)^{-1}
$$
which, by the way, tells that the order of arguments would be more intuitive in reverse.

Comment: what do you mean for the first sentence?

Comment: What is $Φ(x)$, what is $Ψ(x,x_0)$? They are not defined in your question.

Comment: $\Phi(x,x_0)$ is principal fundamental matrix, and $\Psi(x,x_0)$ is fundamental matrix