# Prove that $y=c_1 y_{1} + c_2 y_2+c_3 y_3$ is a solution of non homogeneous equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1,y_2,y_3$ be $n$ linearly independent solution of the $n^{th}$ order homogeneous differential equation

$y'''+p_1 y''+p_2y'+p_3y=0$

where $p_i$ are function of $x$.

I want to prove that $y=c_1 y_{1} + c_2 y_2+c_3 y_3$ is a solution of non homogeneous equation

$y'''+p_1 y''+p_2y'+p_3y=r(x)$

where $$c_i(x)=\int \frac{D_i(x)}{W(x)}$$ where $D_i(x)$ is the determinant of the matrix obtained from the matrix defining the Wronskian $W(x)$ by replacing its $i^{th}$ column by $[0,0,..., r(x)]^T$

How can I approach to solve this problem? I am stuck.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps my answer to [How exactly is the Wronskian tied with Cramer's rule in a system of ODEs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151773/how-exactly-is-the-wronskian-tied-with-cramers-rule-in-a-system-of-odes?rq=1) would be of help?

Comment: Look up the "method of undetermined coefficients", as that is essentially what you are to derive.